# repeating font-awesome icons causing potential out of memory crash in angular [not browser specific]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using font-awesome 5 icon inside ngFor loop, when I receive use huge chunk of data from server, the browser is paused. If I don't use font-awesome icon in the loop, everything works fine. How can I use icon and avoid potential out of memory crash? Issue persists on all browsers not chrome specific. 
 Please check below Image for error.

[image]

Code:

```
      <tr *ngFor="let data of someList|  orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}; let $index= index" (click)="takeMesomeWhere(data.number, data.cafe)">

      <td>{{ data.number }}</td>
      <td>{{data.cafe}}</td>
      <td>{{data.itemDes}}</td>
      <td class="text-center align-middle cursor-pointer" style="color:red">
        <i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </td>
      // if I remove the above td element, which contains font-awesome icons, everything works fine
     </tr>
```

Comment: It is custom pipe,  I'm using to sort rows. I've tried removing that piece of code, still its causing the same issue.

Comment: how big is your data?

Comment: where do you use `makeIconStandard`?

Comment: I haven't used it anywhere. I guess that's something inside font-awesome library.

Comment: Describe "memory leak"? Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: @ABOS For instance, if I choose 100 days, the data will return 2000 objects, it would be more if the number of days are increased. data returns faster when checked in postman.